# If $X$ is not second countable, then $X$ has a subspace of cardinality $\aleph_1$ that is not second countable.

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm trying to read this proof from Dow's [An Introduction to Applications of Elementary Submodels to Topology.](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v13/tp13102.pdf) (Proposition 3.2.)

Let $M$ be a elementary submodel of large enough $H(\Theta)$ such that $M$ is $\omega$-covering, $(X,\tau)\in M$, and $|M|=\aleph_1$. I understand how proving that $\{U\cap M\mid U\in \tau\cap M\}$ generates the subspace topology for $X\cap M$ gives the result. So I just need help proving this.

The proof of this fact goes like this: Take $U$ an open set of $X\cap M$ with the subspace topology. There's a countable dense subset of $X\cap M\setminus U$ call it $D$, as $M$ is $\omega$-covering there's a countable $D'\in M$ such that $D\subset D'$. Here Dow says that it follows from $M\models D'\cup \{x\}$ is second countable, that there's a set $T\in\tau\cap M$ such that $x\in T$ and $T\cap D'\subset U$.

I haven't been able to verify this last implication.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $M$ here? And if $X$ is your initial space, then $U \cap X$ should just be $U$?

Comment: Also: There are countable spaces which are not second-countable. They obviously don't have any non-second countable subspaces of cardinality $\aleph_1$, so something is off about the statement to prove.

Comment: @Arno Thank you for your comment. I was sleepy when writing the question, fixed some details now. $(U\cap X$ was supposed to be $U\cap M)$. I worded the result a bit unprecisely, there is a subspace of size at most $\aleph_1$ that is not secound countable is the true conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a countable $B\in M$ such that $M\models B$ is a base for $D'\cup \{x\}$. But, being countable, $B$ is actually a subset of $M$. Now, as $$H(\theta)\models B \text{ is a base for }D'\cup \{x\}.$$ and $U\cap D'$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $D'\cup \{x\}$, there's a $T\in B$ such that $$x\in T\cap D' \subset U\cap D'\subset U.$$ 
But this $T$ is actually in $M\cap\tau$ because $B$ is a subset of $M$.

The point here is that $M$ can't talk about $U$ because it doesn't know it exists, but $H(\Theta)$ can. And as $B$ is exactly the same set in $M$ and $H(\Theta)$, the open set $H(\Theta)$ finds is also in $M$.